# How to print data of a Local JSON File in text field

Tags: objective-c, json

Ok here is my local json file products.json which i placed under the resources folder :

```
   "Products": [
                 {
                 "Name": "Samsung LCD",
                 "Price": "40000",
                 "Ratings": 4.5,
                 "Barcode":1
                 },
                 {
                 "Name": "Sony Cybershot",
                 "Price": "35000",
                 "Ratings": 3.5,
                 "Barcode":2
                 },
                 {
                 "Name": "LG Refrigerator",
                 "Price": "40000",
                 "Ratings": 4,
                 "Barcode":3
                 },
                 {
                 "Name":"Toshiba Microwave"  ,
                 "Price": "Hdhd",
                 "Ratings": 4.5,
                 "barcode":4
                 }
                 ]
```

I have a text field on which i want to print data of the 1st product i.e. samsung lcd on click of a button.

here's the code: (its showing null output) also do i need to import any file ?

- (IBAction)enterCode:(id)sender {

  ```
  NSLog(@"HI");

  NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"products" ofType:@"json"]

  NSError *error = nil;

  NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];

  id JSONObject = [NSJSONSerialization
                   JSONObjectWithData:JSONData
                   options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                   error:&error];

  _out1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                @"%@ %@ %@ %@",
                JSONObject[@"products"][0][@"Name"],
                JSONObject[@"products"][0][@"Price"],
                JSONObject[@"products"][0][@"Ratings"],
                JSONObject[@"products"][0][@"Barcode"],
                nil];
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

JSON parsed dictionaries use case-sensetive strings as keys. Your json has main key as `Products`, when you're referencing in your code to `products`. Use `JSONObject[@"Products"][0][@"Name"]` instead of your version.

Also, check that your products.json file is included in your application target in Xcode, otherwise it won't be copied to the app's bundle.